# how to specify issuer address in WS2007FederationBinding?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

I am just creating a custom binding in C# to use a WS2007FederationBinding - it is a client application calling a service.  I have most of it working but am getting an error:

> *The address of the security token issuer is not specified. An explicit issuer address must be specified in the binding for target*

I am using TransportWithMessageCredential as my security mode. The token issuer is not local.

I have added both a WSFederationHttpSecurity and an IssuedSecurityTokenParameters both setting the keyType (symmetric), TokenType (#SAMLV2.0), IssuerAddress and IssuerMetadataAddress.

I have not set the IssuerBinding (could not find any documentation).

This is resulting in either a 'no version of cardspace found' or the above message.

Does anyone have a link to a working example - so I can see what settings I might be missing?

Update:  Have added the shape of the config binding I am trying to emulate in C#.

```
<ws2007FederationBinding>
  <binding name="">
     <security mode="transportwithmessagecredential"
        <message issuedTokenType="..."
             <issuer address="" binding="" bindingConfiguration="">...
             <tokenRequestParams>
                  <trust:secondaryParameters>
```

The problem I am having is that the Issuer Address also contain a binding and bindingConfiguration attribute. But I can't find an example on how to add these.

I found a .net core example on github but it is missing this piece.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/ws2007federationhttpbinding

Comment: Thanks, although I should have said I am doing it in C# and not using config files. I have managed to get it to say 'the provided uri scheme https is invalid. expected http. parameter name 'via'.   I created a ServiceMetadataBehaviour with httpGet enabled, but cannot work out how to add it.   The examples use serviceHost, but this does not exist in a ws2007federationbinding

Comment: I updated my original post to clarify

Comment: You can download the wcf service samples of the official document, there are some examples that may be helpful to you. This is the link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/

Comment: Hi thanks,  I had a look through it. As far as I could see it just contained references to web.config bindings and not C# in-code. Also, I could not find anything on connecting to ws2007FederationBinding using a client.